# Place table footnotes and legend

Tags: tables, footnotes

I'm trying to reproduce the following table in latex:

[image]

But I can't put the table footnotes under the table. I would also like to add who is the author of the table below, as is done in the figures.

[image]

```
\begin{table}[htb!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
%\small % <-- optional
\caption{Correntes de \textit{inrush} para diferentes conexões do transformador}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} cccccc }
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Conexão do} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Banco de} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Transformador} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Transformador} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Transformadores } &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Trifásico} \\
\cmidrule{1-2} \cmidrule{3-4} \cmidrule{5-6}
Primário  & Secundário & Chaveamento & Chaveamento & Chaveamento & Chaveamento  \\
          &            & Simultâneo  & Sequencial  & Simultâneo  & Sequencial   \\
\midrule
 Y (Aterrado) & $\Delta$ ou Y & 26$\times$normal... & 26$\times$normal... & 13$\times$normal... & 14.5$\times$normal... \\
 Y (Aterrado) & $\Delta$      & 26$\times$normal... & 29$\times$normal... & 13$\times$normal... & 14.5$\times$normal... \\
\addlinespace
 Y            & $\Delta$ ou Y & 20$\times$normal... & 20$\times$normal... & 11$\times$normal... &   11$\times$normal... \\
 Y            & $\Delta$      & 20$\times$normal... & 20$\times$normal... & 11$\times$normal... &   11$\times$normal... \\
\addlinespace
 $\Delta$     & $\Delta$ ou Y & 20*$\times$normal...& 30\textdagger$\times$normal...& 15.5\textdaggerdbl$\times$normal...  & 15.5\textdaggerdbl$\times$normal... \\
 $\Delta$     & $\Delta$      & 20*$\times$normal...& 30\textdagger$\times$normal...& 15.5\textdaggerdbl$\times$normal... & 15.5\textdaggerdbl$\times$normal...\\
\bottomrule   
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}
```

I'm using the following compiler: pt.overleaf.com/latex/templates/pcall-tcc/dywydszxydqd. And the document class is abntex2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to suggest you employ machinery of the [threeparttable](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) package. Use `\tnote{...}` directives -- where `...` could be `\textasteriskcentered`, `\textdagger`, or `\textdagggerdbl` -- inside the `tabular` environment to plant footnote markers. Then, use a `tablenotes` environment with `\item[...]` directives to typeset the corresponding footnote texts.

No special machinery seems to be needed for the Source attribution; see the code below for an implementation of this claim.

[image]

```
\documentclass{abntex2}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}  % <-- new

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Correntes de \textit{inrush} para diferentes conexões do transformador}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} cccccc }
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Conexão do} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Banco de} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Transformador} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Transformador} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Transformadores } &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Trifásico} \\
\cmidrule{1-2} \cmidrule{3-4} \cmidrule{5-6}
Primário  & Secundário & Chaveamento & Chaveamento & Chaveamento & Chaveamento  \\
          &            & Simultâneo  & Sequencial  & Simultâneo  & Sequencial   \\
\midrule
 Y (Aterrado) & $\Delta$ ou Y & 26$\times$normal... & 26$\times$normal... & 13$\times$normal... & 14.5$\times$normal... \\
 Y (Aterrado) & $\Delta$      & 26$\times$normal... & 29$\times$normal... & 13$\times$normal... & 14.5$\times$normal... \\
\addlinespace
 Y            & $\Delta$ ou Y & 20$\times$normal... & 20$\times$normal... & 11$\times$normal... &   11$\times$normal... \\
 Y            & $\Delta$      & 20$\times$normal... & 20$\times$normal... & 11$\times$normal... &   11$\times$normal... \\
\addlinespace
 $\Delta$     & $\Delta$ ou Y & 
20\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}$\times$normal...& 
30\tnote{\textdagger}$\times$normal...& 
15.5\tnote{\textdaggerdbl}$\times$normal...  & 
15.5\tnote{\textdaggerdbl}$\times$normal... \\
 $\Delta$     & $\Delta$      & 
20\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}$\times$normal...& 
30\tnote{\textdagger}$\times$normal...& 
15.5\tnote{\textdaggerdbl}$\times$normal... & 
15.5\tnote{\textdaggerdbl}$\times$normal...\\
\bottomrule   
\end{tabular*}

\smallskip
\small
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[\textasteriskcentered] Based on normal phase current; equals 11.5 based on normal line current.
\item[\textdagger] Based on normal phase current; equals 17.3 based on normal line current.
\item[\textdaggerdbl] Based on normal phase current; equals \phantom{0}9.0 based on normal line current.
\end{tablenotes}

\smallskip
\centering
Fonte: \textsc{el hawary} (1986)

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay, I was trying through tablefootnote, but the text I typed after the command didn't show up. Only the footnote number.

Thank you again !!!

Comment: @Dragnovith - You're welcome. The `threeparttable` package, and its `\tnote` commands`, is particularly useful when typesetting symbolic footnote markers that may occur repeatedly in the table.

Answer (score 1):

#### lrbox and \tablefoot solution

Mico provided a good answer, but threeparttable hasn't been updated in 19 years, so I worry that it's unmaintained. I also needed the footer to align perfectly with the table. Finally, I often needed plain text as the footer rather than a footnote list.

The approach I used is to create a box via `\newsavebox`, use it with `\begin{lrbox}` inside `table`, then use it in a `\tablefoot` macro.

```latex
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\RequirePackage{caption}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
%\RequirePackage{enumitem}      % may be useful
%\RequirePackage{tabularray}    % LaTeX3 tabular replacement
%\RequirePackage{booktabs}      % professional-quality tables
%\RequirePackage{csvsimple-l3}  % load CSV data

\def\captionstretch{1.0} % line spacing
\captionsetup[table]%
{
    labelfont={small,sf,bf,stretch=\captionstretch},
    textfont={small,sf,bf,stretch=\captionstretch},
    position=above
}

\newsavebox{\tablebox}

\ProvideDocumentEnvironment{smarttable}{}%
{ \begin{table}\centering \begin{lrbox}{\tablebox} }%
{ \end{lrbox} \end{table} }%
\ProvideDocumentEnvironment{smarttable*}{}%
{ \begin{table*}\centering \begin{lrbox}{\tablebox} }%
{ \end{lrbox} \end{table*} }

\ProvideDocumentCommand{\tablefoot}{m}%
{{
    \setstretch{\captionstretch} \sffamily
    \usebox{\tablebox}\\[\medskipamount]
    \parbox{\wd\tablebox}{ \small #1 }
}}
```

##### To use:

```latex
\begin{document}
\begin{smarttable}
\begin{tabular*}
table contents ...
\end{tabular*}
\tablefoot{
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
\item[\textasteriskcentered] Based on normal phase current; equals 11.5 based on normal line current.
\item[\textdagger] Based on normal phase current; equals 17.3 based on normal line current.
\item[\textdaggerdbl] Based on normal phase current; equals \phantom{0}9.0 based on normal line current.
\end{itemize}
}
\end{smarttable}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help too!